# When should I store JSON in a database?

Tags: mysql, json, database

I am working with a big database in MySql and I would like to know when is good to store data in JSON format instead of creating other tables.

Thanks.

Comment: When your JSON data represents a structured document or object-graph that cannot easily be represented as relational-data.

Comment: Also, define "big database"  - that's subjective - are we talking tens of millions of rows? Because if you have really big data, then it's important that the data you're working with is fully decomposed and directly queryable. We need more context.

Comment: Also, remember JSON is *just a notation*, it does not describe the nature of the data you're working with. You can represent CSV files as a legal subset of JSON, for example, yet that's a top example of data that *should* be (and can easily-be) converted into relational tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible use cases for JSON format in a classic database:

1. To avoid creating a table for unstructured data, enabling you to store data with any structure.
2. To store data used directly by REST apps
3. To avoid creating a table for data that does not need to be filtered or aggregated (e.g., `SUM`, `MAX`, etc.)
4. For the added benefit of not having to write any JSON parsing code; the ORM or the language runtime takes care of it.
5. When you need transfer load and parse from database to programming language same as `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT search or index data expressed as JSON. It would be not very meaningful. It would be like a BLOB from DB's point of view.

So basically, you would just slap it into the database, and do not do anything with it? Then this begs the question whether you really need that JSON data at all?

If you are going to use bits and pieces of it more actively, then it makes sense to (at least those parts that you are interested in) get those parts out of JSON and put them in proper tables etc. That way you can search, index, relate these bits of data with others in a more meaningful way.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is no longer true - MySQL>=5.7.8 supports JSON as a native data type with some support for indexing - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Comment: @JohnCarter Excerpt from your own link: "As noted elsewhere, JSON columns cannot be indexed directly. To create an index that references such a column indirectly, you can define a generated column that extracts the information that should be indexed, then create an index on the generated column"  So basically, mysql provides a handy mechanism to single out bits of JSON to index it, just like I mentioned in my answer.